# Error applying fitMarkovChain

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a list of clickstreams to a Markov chain, using 
`fitMarkovChain` function of library(clickstream).

I've run this piece of code a few months ago and it worked. Now the output is an error:

**Error in solve.default(It - Q) : 'a' must be a complex matrix**

```
library(clickstream)
id<-c("123","456","789")
path<-c("Entrance,A,B,A,C,Exit","Entrance,A,C,A,C,B,Exit","Entrance,B,Exit")
clickstreams<-paste(id,path,sep=",")
csf<-tempfile()
writeLines(clickstreams,csf)
cls<-readClickstreams(csf,header=T)
mc<-fitMarkovChain(cls)
```

Any idea about what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me. Try restarting and starting your code with `rm(list = ls())`.

Comment: Thanks, ddunn801. Restarting it works again.